# WordPress Link To Image Missing Dropdown

Tags: images, wp-admin, media-library

I am on the latest version of WordPress. When adding/editing a image in Wordpress there's the **Link To Image** which normally provides a dropdown menu. For me it's a blank text box and I don't know how to fix it. I have uninstalled plugins with no luck. It's cross-browser on both Chrome and Firefox. Screenshot attached.

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: any JS errors ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what that section looks like to me.

[image]

Are you sure your not adding custom fields some where?  Are you trying to use the "Link To" setting for an image block?  See below.

[image]